# RHEL yum update commad failed in aws ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rhel, amazon-efs

While running `$ sudo yum -y update` in RHEL, the execution failed with the error message:

> Could not open: jenkins-2.249.1-1.1.noarch.rpm
> error: gpg check failed.

Why do I get this error message and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Update Red Hat or its compatible operating systems using the below command:

```
rpm --import https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.io.key
```

Then execute

```
$ sudo yum -y update
```

If the above package is out of date in the future, please click here to read more info: https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2020/07/27/repository-signing-keys-changing/